# User is authenticated only for some routes of the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, routes

Below is the code for my controller. Surprisingly when I log in it appears that I am logged only for some {instruments}.

```
[Route("Data/{instrument}")]
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600,Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server,VaryByParam = "instrument")]
public ActionResult Index(string instrument)
{
    DataViewList dane = new DataViewList(instrument);
    return View("Index", "_LayoutChooseInst", dane);
}
```

Comment: Clearly what is happening here is you are caching some instruments before you login and then when you login they are still being retrieved from the cache. Looks like you need a different caching strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thougth that when I cache on server is independant on the user